# The proper way to add columns to Sales Order Grid in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am looking for a way to add columns to the Sales/Order grid in Magento. There are many tutorials but I find that they involve overriding Core files by placing them in the Local CodePool and this isn't always good practice.

I am trying to add:

Postcode,
Address, 
Email,
Telephone,
OrderID,
CustomerID

If anyone can share a solution or extension that I could use to achieve this without the Core override I'd be extremely grateful.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gridcontrol>
    <grids>
        <!-- grid id -->
        <sales_order_grid>
            <shipping_description>
                <add>
                    <header>Shipping Description</header>
                    <!-- join shipping description from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales/order" condition="main_table.entity_id={{table}}.entity_id" field="shipping_description"/>
                </add>
               <after>status</after>
            </shipping_description>
            <shipping_address>
                <add>
                    <header>Shipping Address</header>
                    <!-- join shipping description from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales/order" condition="main_table.entity_id={{table}}.entity_id" field="shipping_address"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </shipping_address>
            <Billing_address>
                <add>
                    <header>Billing Address</header>
                    <!-- join shipping description from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales/order" condition="main_table.entity_id={{table}}.entity_id" field="billing_address"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </Billing_address>
            <Telephone>
                <add>
                    <header>Telephone</header>
                    <!-- join shipping description from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales/order" condition="main_table.entity_id={{table}}.entity_id" field="telephone"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </Telephone>
            <CustomerID>
                <add>
                    <header>Customer ID</header>
                    <!-- join shipping description from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales/order" condition="main_table.entity_id={{table}}.entity_id" field="customer_id"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </CustomerID>
        </sales_order_grid>
    </grids>
</gridcontrol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree overriding is not good, but you can create a new module and extend the functionalities of Order grid and add your new attributes. This way you will simply need to de-activate the module to disable it's functionality.

If you don't know how to do this, here is a nice tutorial by inchoo blog:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

Comment: Is possible can i add a custom attribute to sales order grid?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl for this. Just install the extension and write a second one with a gridcontrol.xml with the desired content.

Comment: This seems close to what I need. I've installed the extension but I don't know what you mean by "and write a second one". Please give some more instruction.

Comment: You shouldn't change the module, so putting the gridcontrol.xml into the module would be the wrong way if you ask me. Therefore you need a second module to put the gridcontrol.xml into the etc directory

Comment: I've installed the module as is: Now I need to create a second module with the gridcontrol.xml file inside the etc folder where I make changes, so should I remove the gridcontrol.xml file from the original module first?

Comment: I haven't used this method to add columns to admin grid before. I think it would be useful to other users to also know how to do this as the extension provided by @Fabian Blechschmidt works. I am trying to figure out which table(s) to use for the required output as the fields I have added are not showing any values. If I figure it out I will post back!

Comment: You have to join into the sales_order_address table to add `postcode`, `street`, `city` and `telephone`. And you can easily add the attributes `customer_id`, `entity_id` (order id)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25436/discussion-between-user1704524-and-fabian-blechschmidt)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not your personal trainer.

Comment: Fair enough, considering I am using your solution but I will figure it out.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is possible can i add a custom attribute to sales order grid?

Comment: Did you read the readme? You can join and add whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
copy and past code 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','city','postcode' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing'");
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('total_qty_ordered'));
         $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"', array('sfoa.street', 'sfoa.city', 'sfoa.region', 'sfoa.postcode', 'sfoa.telephone'));
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',array('method'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _getAttributeOptions($attribute_code)
        {
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
            $options = array();
            foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option ) {
                $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }
            return $options;
        }
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date'),//Date=Purchased On
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',//
        ));
        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Id'), //Order #=order id
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'=> 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.increment_id',
        ));
        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'=> 'store_id',
        'type'=> 'store',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id',
        'store_view'=> true,
        'display_deleted' => true,
        ));
        }
        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Name'), //Bill to Name=Customer Name
        'index' => 'billing_name',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.billing_name',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Mobile'),
        'index' => 'telephone',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.telephone',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('city', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('City'),
        'index' => 'city',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.city',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('postcode', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pincode'),
        'index' => 'postcode',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.postcode',
        ));
         $this->addColumn('city', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('City'),
               'index' => 'city', 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_addEGColumnFilter'),
           ));
           $this->addColumn('street', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Street'),
               'index' => 'street',
               'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_addEGColumnFilter'),
           ));
           $this->addColumn('postcode', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Postcode'),
               'index' => 'postcode',
               'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_addEGColumnFilter'),
           ));
           $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Telephone'),
               'index' => 'telephone',
               'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ customColumnFilter'),
           ));
        $this->addColumn('method', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment method'),
        'index' => 'method',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_payment.method',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
        'index' => 'total_qty_ordered',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.total_qty_ordered',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('color', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Color'),
        'index' => 'color',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.color',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order amount'),//G.T. (Purchased)=Order amount
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'type'=> 'currency',
        'currency'=> 'order_currency_code',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.grand_total',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.status',
        'type' => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
        'width'=> '50px',
        'type'=> 'action',
        'getter' => 'getId',
        'actions'=> array(
        array(
        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
        'url' => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
        'field' => 'order_id'
        )
        ),
        'filter'=> false,
        'sortable'=> false,
        'index' => 'stores',
        'is_system' => true,
        ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }


    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain how your solution works? The OP specifically states that they want to "achieve this without the Core override" but your code would have to go into the app/local dir to work.